# How do I stop showing the "for" loop result?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Here is my code:

```
from functools import partial

def x_in_y(word, inner):
    return inner in word

wrong = ['mann','connaction','tee','rigt','putt']
sentence=['this mann is my son','the connaction is unstable','my tee is getting cold','put your hands down','rigt now','right behind my back']

for i in wrong:
    print(f"Wrong: {i}")
    filtered_names = filter(partial(x_in_y, inner=i), sentence)
    for name in filtered_names:
        print(name)
```

Please tell me how do i only show the matches without the others? (In this case, remove "wrong:putt")

Like:

```
Wrong: mann
this mann is my son
Wrong: connaction
the connaction is unstable
Wrong: tee
my tee is getting cold
Wrong: rigt
rigt now
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want print names only if they appear in at least one sentence, Just move the `print(f"Wrong: {i}")` below the `filtered_names` and check iterator that is empty with [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)like this:

```
for i in wrong:
    filtered_names = filter(partial(x_in_y, inner=i), sentence)
    next_elem = next(filtered_names, None)
    if next_elem:
        print(f"Wrong: {i}") 
        print(next_elem)
    for name in filtered_names:
        print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! But "Wrong:putt" still in the result. And it should be disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply nesting for loops?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           

wrong = ["mann", "connaction", "tee", "rigt", "putt"]                       
sentences = [                                                               
    "this mann is my son",                                                  
    "the connaction is unstable",                                           
    "my tee is getting cold",                                               
    "put your hands down",                                                  
    "rigt now",                                                             
    "right behind my back",                                                 
]                                                                           

for word in wrong:                                                          
    for sentence in sentences:                                              
        if word in sentence:                                                
            print(f"Wrong: {word}")                                         
            print(sentence)
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked. But would it be slower than mine because there are two "for" loops?

Comment: possibly. to answer this one would need to look into the internals of `filter` I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

How could I add a correct word next to each labels? then it implies the correct word for each result.

Like this one:

```
Wrong: mann "should be man"
this mann is my son
Wrong: connaction "should be connection"
the connaction is unstable
Wrong: tee "should be tea"
my tee is getting cold
Wrong: rigt "should be right"
rigt now
```